# find parameter for which function have 2 asymptotes

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

[image]

$a$ is a real parameter.

We need to find $a$ ( must probably, intervals ) such as $f$ admits $2$ asymptotes.

I found out that $f$ admits oblique asymptotes, $y=x + a$, for $a\neq0$

General form: $ y=mx+n $, where:

$m = lim(f(x)/x)= lim (e^{a/x})$ = 1 as $ x $ $->$ $\infty$

$n = lim(f(x)- x) = lim[x(e^{a/x}-1)] = a$ as $ x $ $->$ $\infty$

I don't know what conditions over $a$ to put for vertical asymptote(s), in order to get a solution for this problem

Comment: Note that $f(x)$ will always have a vertical asymptote at $x=0$ if $a\ne 0$.

Comment: @Tavish but the answer should be $(0,\infty )$ ( I've cheated, i've looked at the book responses )

Comment: I’ve graphed it and checked that there is indeed one asymptote at negative $a$, too.

Comment: for $a\neq0$ we get oblique asymptote ( $y = x + a$ ) and vertical asymptote ( to $ \infty$ ). I don't know why the answer is $a>0$

Comment: Maybe it’s a misprint.

Comment: Please include important parts of your question as text, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions, instead of pasting pictures (and blurry ones as that) of them. This question is almost incomprehensible without that image, which makes it inaccessible to people who depend on screen readers. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor show up in summaries.